Is Sarah Harding canonically the daughter of Dr. Gerry Harding?
In Jurassic Park, the park vet with the ill Triceratops is Dr. Gerry Harding.
The female protagonist played by Julianne Moore in Jurassic Park: The Lost World is Dr. Sarah Harding.
Jurassic Park: The Game links Gerry as being the father of Sarah, as well as having another child.
The fandom page for the Sarah Harding character states:

While she is confirmed to be the daughter of Dr. Gerry Harding in the film canon, and has a half sister named Jessica Harding, both of whom were involved in the Jurassic Park Incident and its aftermath, her relationship with Gerry Harding is only implied in The Lost World.

How is Sarah's relationship to Gerry implied in the Lost World, and is this relationship cannon within the series?

In the script and novel (and movie credits) he's just Dr. Harding. The name Gerry seems to have been added at a later date for the game and the junior novelisation; "Next to the Triceratops crouched Dr. Gerry Harding. Dr. Harding was the animal caretaker for the park. He was examining the dinosaur."

In the novels she's (semi-)confirmed to be the vet's daughter from Jurassic Park. ("Before coming to the park, Harding had been the chief of veterinary medicine at the San Diego Zoo, and the world's leading expert on avian care. - Jurassic Park by Michael Crichton) (Malcolm looked up sharply. "Your father was a vet?" "Yes. At the San Diego Zoo. He was a bird specialist. But I don't see…Can you magnify this?" Jurassic Park: The Lost World by Michael Crichton)
